# Conditional is not met with return from mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I should complete below condition if `total_money` in table **total_balance** 
is greater than `10` for exact user message sholud be display but doesn't work

**Any syntax or logical error??**
How to solve?

```
 <?php
     $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '********', '**********', '*********');

      $user_check_query =  "SELECT total_money FROM total_balance WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      if($result >10){
          echo "Enough";
        } else {
            echo "Not Enough Money";
      }
      ?>
```

**table:** `total_balance`

```
 ID   username        total_money
+----+--------------+---------------+
|1   | John         |  100          |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|2   | Alex         |  10           |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|3   | Pani         |  5            |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: You should be testing `$row['total_money'] > 10`, not `$result > 10`

Comment: @Nick Solved! Appreciate you!

Comment: @YourCommonSense excellent dupe. I'll have to remember that one. Pity you didn't quite get there in time to prevent an answer.

Comment: @Nick I didn't know the dupe, I just made up the error message it should produce and here it was the first result from google.

Comment: @YourCommonSense funny how often they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if($result >10){
          echo "Enough";
        } else {
            echo "Not Enough Money";
      }
```

to

```
if($row['total_money']  >10){
          echo "Enough";
        } else {
            echo "Not Enough Money";
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for the hint